# Submodules: how to divide C++ module into submodules

Tags: c++, visual-studio, module, c++20

I have a simple project with one module.

Units.ixx

```
module;

#include <cassert>
export module Units;
export class Base {
public:
};
export void foo();
```

Units_impl.ixx

```
export module Units;

class Derived : public Base {  // 'Base': base class undefined
};

export void foo() {
    Derived derived;
}
```

Main.cpp

```
import Units;

int main() {
    return foo();
}
```

Compiler shows me an error 'Base': base class undefined.
Is it expected behavior? If yes, how to divide modules into submodules? I’d like to have Derived inside my Units module but in a different file.

Comment: It may not be related to the real issue, but you can’t have `export` in a file that doesn’t use `export module …;`: just omit it from the definition of `foo`.

Comment: thx. added export. the problem is the same

Comment: But you can’t have two primary interface units for the same module!

Comment: It's not clear in this example what is supposed to be the public interface and the private interface.

Answer (score 3):

Module.ixx

```
export module mybar;

export import :Wheel;
export import :Bus;
```

Wheel.ixx

```
export module mybar:Wheel;

export 
class Wheel{
};
```

Bus.ixx

```
export module mybar:Bus;
import :Wheel;

export 
class Bus :public Wheel {
};
```

Answer (score 1):

To split a module into multiple files you need to use partitions. To do this you need to first create a primary interface:

```
export module Units;
```

then you declare each separate file that makes up the module as a named partition(export module <module_name>:<partition_name>) eg:

```
export module Units:Impl;
```

This does not by itself share classes, variables or functions between the files though. To access a partition from the primary interface or another partition you need to add an import statement import :<partition_name> eg:

```
import :Impl;
```

so in the code you have above Units_impl.ixx knows nothing about `Base` as it is declared in a separate file hence the error.

This also means you cannot declare the class Base in the primary interface if you want to have access to it from a partition as this would result in a cyclic dependancy. Ie the partition would need to import Units(the primary interface) which would itself need to import the partition(Units:Impl). So at the very least your files would need to look something like:

Units.ixx:

```
export module Units;
import :Impl;

export void foo();
```

Units_Impl.ixx:

```
class Base{};
class Derived: public Base{};

export void foo()
{
    Derived derived;
}
```

Main.cpp:

```
import Units;

int main()
{
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

If you didn't want Base to be in the same file as Derived you'd need to create another partition in a separate file eg:

Units_Base.ixx:

```
export Units:Base;
export class Base{};
```

and then your Units_Impl.ixx would look like this:

```
export Units:Impl;
import :Base;

class Derived: public Base{};

export void foo()
{
    Derived derived;
}
```

Finally you can re-export from an imported module using export import <module_or_partition_name> eg:

```
export import :Impl;
```

this would then make `export void foo();` in Units.ixx unnecessary and it would look like this:

```
export module Units;
export import :Impl;
```

Comment: Can there be nested module partitions? Such as `Units:Impl:Impl1`?

Comment: No there cannot. You'd have to make Impl or Impl1 a module of their own and import as normal.

Comment: The spec went a little over my head, so thank you very much for clarifying that!